# Get unique value for last 10 minutes data - mysql

Tags: mysql

---

-- Table structure for `data2`

---

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `data2`;
CREATE TABLE `data2` (
  `ID` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `DTIME` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `NUM` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `VALUE` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `REF` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `NOD` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=2033 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

---

-- Records of data2

---

```
INSERT INTO `data2` VALUES ('2015', '2014-02-07 00:05:00', '120', '1491900', '1', 'AA');
INSERT INTO `data2` VALUES ('2016', '2014-02-07 00:10:00', '120', '1491901', '1', 'AA');
INSERT INTO `data2` VALUES ('2017', '2014-02-07 00:15:00', '120', '1491902', '1', 'AA');
INSERT INTO `data2` VALUES ('2018', '2014-02-07 00:05:00', '120', '1491903', '1', 'BB');
INSERT INTO `data2` VALUES ('2019', '2014-02-07 00:15:00', '120', '1491904', '1', 'BB');
INSERT INTO `data2` VALUES ('2020', '2014-02-07 00:05:00', '120', '1491905', '1', 'BB');
INSERT INTO `data2` VALUES ('2021', '2014-02-07 00:10:00', '200', '1491906', '1', 'CC');
INSERT INTO `data2` VALUES ('2022', '2014-02-07 00:15:00', '200', '1491907', '1', 'CC');
INSERT INTO `data2` VALUES ('2023', '2014-02-07 00:05:00', '200', '1491908', '1', 'CC');
INSERT INTO `data2` VALUES ('2024', '2014-02-07 00:15:00', '200', '1491909', '1', 'AA');
INSERT INTO `data2` VALUES ('2025', '2014-02-07 00:05:00', '200', '1491910', '1', 'AA');
INSERT INTO `data2` VALUES ('2026', '2014-02-07 00:10:00', '200', '1491911', '1', 'AA');
INSERT INTO `data2` VALUES ('2027', '2014-02-07 00:15:00', '800', '1491912', '1', 'AA');
INSERT INTO `data2` VALUES ('2028', '2014-02-07 00:05:00', '800', '1491913', '1', 'AA');
INSERT INTO `data2` VALUES ('2029', '2014-02-07 00:15:00', '800', '1491914', '1', 'BB');
INSERT INTO `data2` VALUES ('2030', '2014-02-07 00:05:00', '800', '1491915', '1', 'BB');
INSERT INTO `data2` VALUES ('2031', '2014-02-07 00:10:00', '800', '1491916', '1', 'BB');
INSERT INTO `data2` VALUES ('2032', '2014-02-07 00:15:00', '800', '2120449', '0', 'BB');
```

I have samples data above , What i want is get the latest data for unique NUM-NOD data. How to get the output bellow with just mysql query

```
'2014-2-7 00:15:00',120,1491902, 1,'AA'
'2014-2-7 00:15:00',120,1491904, 1,'BB'
'2014-2-7 00:15:00',200,1491907, 1,'CC'
'2014-2-7 00:15:00',200,1491909, 1,'AA'
'2014-2-7 00:15:00',800,1491912, 1,'AA'
'2014-2-7 00:15:00',800,2120449, 0,'BB'
```

New data will be added every 5 minutes from  each NODE but sometimes data for some NOD will delayed ( last date time data will not always equal for all NOD)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM data2
WHERE DTIME > '2014-02-07 00:10:00'
ORDER BY DTIME DESC
```

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d767f/3)

Comment: The are always new data on every 5 minutes how to make conditional more dynamic ?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT * 
FROM data2
WHERE DTIME > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 MINUTE) 
ORDER BY DTIME DESC
```

That should do it just fine.